# Object doesn't support this property or method (custom prototype method of custom object)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have this code:

```
function Event(fromDate, toDate, color) {
    if (toDate < fromDate) {
        throw "Invalid date interval";
    }
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
    this.toDate = toDate;
    this.color = color;
}

Event.prototype._compareDates = function (date1, date2) {
    if (date1 && date2) {
        return date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};

Event.prototype.inInterval = function (date) {
    return (this._compareDates(date, this.fromDate) >= 0) && (this._compareDates(date, this.toDate) <= 0);
};

Event.prototype.isCoveredBy = function (event) {
    return (this._compareDates(event.fromDate, this.fromDate) < 0) && (this._compareDates(event.toDate, this.toDate) > 0);
};

Event.prototype.overlapsWith = function (event) {
    return this.inInterval(event.fromDate) || this.inInterval(event.toDate) || this.isCoveredBy(event);
};

var event1 = new Event(new Date(), new Date(), "#ffffff");
var event2 = new Event(new Date(), new Date(), "#ffffff");

alert(event1.overlapsWith(event2));
```

It works on Chrome and Firefox, but on Internet Explorer 11 it looks like it cannot finde any of the Event.prototype.foo functions and throws error "object doesn't support this property or method 'foo'.

UPDATE:

The problem was with this code:

```
function saveOrUpdate(color) {
    var fromDate = PF('fromDate').getDate();
    var toDate = PF('toDate').getDate();
    event = new Event(fromDate, toDate, color);
    $('#inlineDatepicker').datepick('addOrUpdateEvent', event);
    $('#inlineDatepicker').datepick('clear');
}
```

It gets called from a bean using PrimeFaces RequestContext to add new Events to the Javascript calendar. Notice that the third line does not declare a new variable 'event' as I intended to.

For some reason, IE11 interprets that event is of type Event in the global namespace (see Andrei Nemes answer) and not my own custom type of the same name. Chorme and Firefox interpret the type correctly. So, the solution is to change that third line, adding 'var':

```
var event = new Event(fromDate, toDate, color);
```

I'm sorry a did not post this part of the code before. I will change the name of my Event class to avoid problems in the future.

Comment: Taking at a brief look at your code, I don't see anything actually called 'foo'... is there any code missing? usually if you are using the debug tools, if you click the error, it goes to a line. Do you know which line it's going to?

Comment: @DylanCorriveau as far as I read it, `looks like it cannot find **any** of the Event.prototype.foo functions` does not mean that he tries to access foo(). It means that none of the four functions he actually defined can be found.

Comment: Yes, I meant every Event.propotype function, like "overlapsWith" or "inInterval".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>`Event` already exists in the global namespace. When you are declaring `Event.prototype.overlapsWith` Internet Explorer is attaching it to the native Event object not your class declaration. If you have a look at the `Event` object you can see it there.
Easy fix is to not use the name `Event`.</sub>

Edit: Nevermind, it seems to work. It  still probably isn't a good idea to use the name Event though. Can you add more details about the error?

Comment: No, the local class declaration should shadow the global `Event` constructor.